# crystalReportViewer not showing correct values

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have created a simple report in crystal reports designer version 14, it consists of two tables just a straight link from one to another. when i run the report in the designer i get different values from when i run the report in a crystal report viewer. I thought it was cashing the data somewhere but the report is set not to store the data.

```
        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reportDocu = new ReportDocument();

        TableLogOnInfo tableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;


        reportDocu.Load(@"Inventory.rpt");

        var crTables = reportDocu.Database.Tables;
        connectionInfo.UserID = "user";
        connectionInfo.Password = "pass";

        CrTables = reportDocu.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            tableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            tableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogoninfo);
        }


        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocu;

        crystalReportViewer1.Update();
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

I have looked in the report and i have ticked (using the designer within VS) Design - Default Settings - Reporting - Discard saved data when loading reports.

The report uses a ODBC for a i-series

I have no idea where this data is coming from when the report is run?

Comment: Re "I have no idea where this data is coming from when the report is run?" - maybe it comes from database? Have you checked, what kind of queries your report issues? Another possibility is that you display record values (not aggregates) in group headers-footers - this way displayed data depends on data arrival order, which may be different every time.

Comment: my concern is that it cant be coming from the database as when i run the report from the crystal designer i get the correct value from the database so product123 has 50 in stock then when the c# report viewer it shows 47 there's no groups in the report.

Comment: Wrong database then?

Comment: it is the same database, as i said the odbc connection is defined within the report. it runs fine within the SAP Crystal Reports Designer v14 but not within the vs crystal reports

Answer (score 1):

You Should use dataset and drag your table into the dataset

After that you should try this code I always use this code :-

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

public partial class Student_Report : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection cn;
    // SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        cn = new SqlConnection(str);
        cn.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from StudentReg_mst", cn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "StudentReg_mst");
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Server.MapPath("StudentReport.rpt"));
        rd.SetDataSource(ds);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    }
```

Hope this will help you